# Is it possible to ignore a special character when all text is selected in EditText?

Tags: android, text, textview, keypress, selectall

I have a `EditText`. When I focus on it, all of the text is selected. When the user enters a character, the previous text (selected text) is removed and the new character is inserted in the `EditText`.

I want to prevent removing the selected text **when** the user inserts character '='.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not aware of the Android OS default behaviors but  a simple and generic way would be to keep the original value of the TextView on focus event and rewrite it back if the newly entered value is "=".

Comment: It sounds like job for TextWatcher.. Please use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html by http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a textwatcher with your EditText ,  it has three methods

```
afterTextChanged(Editable s)
beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
```

Use beforeTextChanged and check if the special character( = or whatever) has been inserted , keep old text

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html